# Invalid double in converting String to Double

Tags: android, double, number-formatting, separator

i get a NumberFormatException : invalid double "111,000,000" in this line of code :

```
double SalePotential = Double.valueOf(EtPotential.getText().toString());
```

in the beginning i've used Numberformat , to format my double value for separating number and inserted it to an EditText but when i try to retrieve the value of EditText it throws me the exception :

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
EtPotential.setText(String.valueOf(f.format(PTData.SalePotential)));
```

i've also tried DecimalFormat or Double.parseDouble with no Success. any help would be Appreciated!  :

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("###.###", DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance());
double SalePotential = Double.parseDouble(EtPotential.getText().toString());
```

Comment: What is the output of this: `String.valueOf(f.format(PTData.SalePotential))`?

Comment: is "111,000,000" the actual input?

Comment: EtPotential.getText().toString() what is the input in edittext?

Comment: @Yoann and shinTakezou : no i set the value 11,000,000 in the EditText then i wanted to edit my EditText to 111,000,000

Comment: that should be 111000000 remove , and try

Comment: yes i know that it should be 111000000 but how can i convert 111,000,000 to 111000000 , as i mentioned before Double.parseDouble or valueof doesn't do this for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove "," before parsing

```
double SalePotential = Double.parseDouble(EtPotential.getText().toString().replace(",", ""));
```

---

Update : With proper implementation

```
double salePotential = 0; // Variable name should start with small letter 
try {
    salePotential = Double.parseDouble(EtPotential.getText().toString().replace(",", ""));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // EditText EtPotential does not contain a valid double
}
```

***Happy coding :)***

Answer (score 1):

Use replace function to replace all occurences of ,

```
     String  s= EtPotential.getText().toString();
     s = s.replace(",", ""); 
     try
     {
       double SalePotential = Double.parseDouble(s);
     }catch(NumberFormatException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```