# Invalid Double. Number format exception in android

Tags: android, numberformatexception

I have this in xml.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/creditlimitfield2"
                android:hint="0"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

So, the default value for edittext is 0.

in code, I have this

```
creditlimit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.creditlimitfield2);
double credit_limit = Double.valueOf(creditlimit.getText().toString());
```

Alternately, I have tried:

```
double credit_limit = Double.parseDouble(creditlimit.getText().toString());
```

And

```
double credit_limit = new Double(creditlimit.getText().toString());
```

When I run the program, It gives the error of

```
Numberformatexception. Invalid double "".
```

Please be reminded that the field is not empty. Any suggestions would be helpful.

---

I have seen many questions,almost similar to it, with very less answers and none of them help solving my condition. So, Please do not tag it as "Similar Question" without checking other questions too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid double in converting String to Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434386/invalid-double-in-converting-string-to-double)

Comment: People, Please read both questions carefully, while tagging it as duplicate.
This question is focusing on the problem, which arises while using the solutions given in that duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getText()` does not return the value inside `android:hint`. So you are trying to convert an empty string as double. use `android:text` property instead.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/creditlimitfield2"
    android:text="0"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Comment: I am pretty sure. Otherwise the getHint() will be really useless.

Comment: @Shasi getText() will not return hint.. it will return text set in EditText

Comment: @JaiSoni then gettext in onResume or on Button click coz you are calling it too soon. may be in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `creditlimit.getText().toString()` does not a return a valid double value. Make sure you enter a valid double in the `EditText`.

```
Numberformatexception. Invalid double ""
```

Empty string is not a valid double.

Also i guess you have this just after initialization make sure you get the text from edittext on button click or in `onResume`

```
double credit_limit = Double.valueOf(creditlimit.getText().toString())
```

If you want the default value follow blackbelt's post.

Comment: @Shasi how can you be sure. You stacktrace suggestion that its not 0 its "" empty string

Comment: @Shasi have a button . enter the number in edittext. get the text from edittext on button click or in onResume. Have you done that??

Answer (score 0):

try this
`Sting limit=creditlimit.getText().toString();
double credit_limit =0;
if(limit!=null && !limit.isEmpty()){
credit_limit = Double.parseDouble(limit);
}`